# Privately published AWS Sumerian scene in React Web App does not include chatbot feature(Polly and Lex)

Tags: reactjs, chatbot, aws-amplify, amazon-lex, amazon-sumerian

I am not able to get the chatbot features to work when the scene is published privately with Amplify, how do I include Polly and Lex in a privately published scene in Sumerian (Publishing it publicly works exactly as it is in the Sumerian editor)?  There is a guide here but it is very vague (Step 5):
https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/tutorials/create/intermediate/amplify-react-2/

Below is my code in app.js

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import './App.css';
 import { withAuthenticator, SumerianScene  } from 'aws-amplify-react';
 import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
 import Aws_exports from './aws-exports';
 import '@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css';
 import AWS, { Polly } from 'aws-sdk';
    
 Amplify.configure(Aws_exports);
 new AWS.Polly();

 class App extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
        <div style={ { height: '100vh' } }>
          <SumerianScene sceneName='Scane1'/>
        </div>
       );
   }
 };

 export default App;
```